# Customize Header Text and Show/Hide in NSOutlineview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am using NSOutlineView in source list mode to display my tree view. I need to change the font color of header text  in groups and disable the show/hide button appear on right hand side. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to change the font color of custom header. You can however disable the show/hide text by responding NO to the delegate method -outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:. The Apple sample code "SidebarDemo" shows this.

https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Implement

```
-(BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item
```

delegate method and return YES for your header rows.

Take a look at this question:
[Changing default font size for NSTable/NSOutlineView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233299/changing-default-font-size-for-nstable-nsoutlineview)

Comment: Already done that but how can change the font color . Lets Make the header text blue etc. ? and disable the right hand show / hide button?